# Similar function to the Java NextInt in C

Tags: c, function

In Java, you can use Scanner.nextInt to get the next input value. I have tried doing this is C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main()
{

    printf("How long is your array?");
    int len;
    scanf("%d",&len);
    printf("Enter %d numbers:",len);
    int array[len];
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++){
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++){
    printf(array[i]);}

    return 0;
}
```

But it will stop before printing the array, which makes me think that this is a false methode.

Comment: Calling `printf` on an arbitrary thing is wishful thinking. Take the time to [read the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) on how that function works before simply jamming arguments into it.

Comment: You should not edit question to change what they ask. The new code is asking a different question, making previous answer(s) mismatched. Stack Overflow is not a service for debugging your program. It is intended to establish a repository of questions and answers for anybody to refer to in the future.

Comment: Look at how you are using `printf` and compare it to `scanf`. What differences do you see? What did you tell `scanf` that you did not tell `printf`? Do you have any documentation that describes `printf` for you?

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 2):

[Note: The question was edited after this answer was written.]

`printf(array);` will not work. You must print the array elements individually, using a loop similar to the one you used to read the values. C has very limited facilities for automatically working with aggregates.

Additionally, `scanf("%d", array[i]);` must be `scanf("%d", &array[i]);`. You need to tell `scanf` **where** to put the value it reads. Passing `array[i]` would tell `scanf` **what** the current value is. `&array[i]` is the address of where `array[i]` is. (When using `printf`, you will pass `array[i]`, because `printf` only needs the value to print. It does not need to know where it is.)

Comment: I have edited those things, thank you. The program will still not do what I want it to...